# Sorting columns in pandas dataframe while automating reports

Tags: pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I am working on an automation task and my dataframe columns are as shown below

```
Defined Discharge Bin   Apr-20  Jan-20  Mar-20  May-20  Grand Total
2-4 min                                             1       1
4-6 min                            5                1       6
6-8 min                            5      7         2       14
```

I want to sort the columns starting from Jan-20. The problem here is that the columns automatically get sorted according to alphabetical order. Sorting can be done manually but since I'm working on an automation task I need to ensure that each month when we feed the data the columns should automatically get sorted according to the months of the year.

Comment: alphabetical sort != months of year sort, can you add your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Defined Discharge Bin':['2-4 min', '4-6 min','6-8 min'], 'Apr-20':['', '', ''], 'Jan-20':['', 5, 5], 'Mar-20':['', '', 7], 'May-20':[1, 1, 2], 'Grand Total':[1, 6, 14]})
cols_exclude = ['Defined Discharge Bin', 'Grand Total']
cols_date = [c for c in df.columns.tolist() if c not in cols_exclude]
cols_sorted = sorted(cols_date, key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%b-%y'))
df = df[cols_exclude[0:1] + cols_sorted + cols_exclude[-1:]]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Defined Discharge Bin Jan-20 Mar-20 Apr-20  May-20  Grand Total
0               2-4 min                            1            1
1               4-6 min      5                     1            6
2               6-8 min      5      7              2           14
```